# Drain cleaner on iodized salt reaction

Tags: organic-chemistry

I poured liquid heat brand drain opener onto iodized salt and didn't get a reaction? I think it's because the sulfuric acid is diluted. If so how can I remove the water or moisture from it?

Comment: And why do you think it wasn't basic cleaner?

Answer (score 0):

According to the MSDS for Liquid Heat drain cleaner the chemical ingredients for the drain cleaner are $\ce{NaClO}$ & $\ce{NaOH}$.

Iodized Salt contains a simple mixture of KI and NaCl.

it makes sense that it doesn't look like much would happen when mixing those two together. $\ce{NaClO}$; however, would react with different substances.

See wikipedia on sodium hypochlorite reactions.

Sources:

https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-chemical-formula-of-Iodized-salt

https://www.menards.com/msds/113502_002.pdf